# Creating a Database on a Shared Directory off the company server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a server through a `SqlCommand` in vb.net. It should create a database on a existing SQL Server running on the company server.

When I created the database on the shared file directory ([`c:\data\` to the server] and [`\\server\data\` as a UNC path]) on a server created on my workstation the UNC path works fine but when using the servers SQL Server I get an error in the filename.

```
 "CREATE DATABASE " & "Setup ON" & _
           "(NAME = " & "Setup " & _
           " FILENAME = N'" & driveletter & strlocation & "\Setup.MDF', " & _
           " SIZE = 5MB, MAXSIZE = 200MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%)" & _
           " LOG ON (NAME = " & "Setup_Log, " & _
           " FILENAME = '" & driveletter & strlocation & "\LOG.LDF', " & _
           " SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 5MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%);"
```

`driveletter` strips the local pc name for the shared directory and gets the unc path for it.
`strlocation` is the file path to the location inside the shared directory.

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server? Up to version 2008, you weren't allowed to create a database file on a network share (see [Create a SQL Server Database on a network share](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varund/archive/2010/09/02/create-a-sql-server-database-on-a-network-shared-drive.aspx) for details):

Comment: SQL 2012 is whats running.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Invalid use of the option FILENAME in the CREATE/ALTER DATABASE statement.